# Equation alignment

Tags: spacing, equations

I'm a little new at this so bear with me. What I intend to get is this:
[image]
I used the following code to obtain it:

```
\begin{flalign*}
\quad f(x) &= e^{x} - x - 1
\medspace\medspace\rightarrow\medspace\medspace
f(0) = e^{0} - 0 - 1 = 0 &\\
\quad f'(x) &= e^{x} - 1
\qquad\medspace\rightarrow\medspace
f'(0) = e^{0} - 1 = 0 &\\
\quad f''(x) &= e^{x}
\qquad\qquad\rightarrow
f''(0) = e^{0} = 1 \neq 0 &
\end{flalign*}
```

I guess there must be an easier way to implement this?

I don't want the equations to be stretched across the whole page with a lot of space in between the individual components. When I try using `&\rightarrow` and `&=`, that's how I end up.

- Should I be using alignat instead?
- But then how would I get it flushed to the left?

Comment: Please always post complete documents (it makes it much easier to test answers). Do you want _all_ equations flush left (eg the global `[fleqn]` option or just this one (it changes possible answers)

Comment: You should consider reading section **25 `align` environments** of the `mathmode` document/[A comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) (specifically look at section **25.2 `alignat` environment**).

Comment: Sorry David, I'll keep that in mind for future reference. I just wanted this one instance flushed left. Also that's a really good resource, Werner, thank you! And thanks strpeter for fixing my original post, this is my first time posting on stackexchange so I'm pretty bad at this.

Comment: @alignmentnewbie for a first posting it's pretty good at least ypu gave some code for people to go on:-) by the way if you prefix a name with @ the system shows possible user names and if you use one the user gets notified. Othewise they only see your reply comments if they happen to visit the question again

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would recommend you use `alignat`:

[image]

### Notes:

- `alignat` provides pairs of `r`ight/`l`eft alignments. Hence the `&&` to get past the `r`ight aligned column and make it a `l`eft aligned column.
- As per egreg's suggestion, I have added a `\quad` spacing around the `\rightarrow`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
f(x) &= e^{x} - x - 1 &&\quad\rightarrow\quad &f(0)   &= e^{0} - 0 - 1 = 0\\
f'(x) &= e^{x} - 1    &&\quad\rightarrow\quad &f'(0)  &= e^{0} - 1 = 0\\
f''(x) &= e^{x}       &&\quad\rightarrow\quad &f''(0) &= e^{0} = 1 \neq 0
\end{alignat*}
or with all the equals also aligned:
\begin{alignat*}{4}
f(x) &= e^{x} - x - 1 &&\quad\rightarrow\quad &f(0)   &= e^{0} - 0 - 1 &&= 0\\
f'(x) &= e^{x} - 1    &&\quad\rightarrow\quad &f'(0)  &= e^{0} - 1     &&= 0\\
f''(x) &= e^{x}       &&\quad\rightarrow\quad &f''(0) &= e^{0}         &&= 1     \neq 0
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some more space around the arrow would be welcome; I had the same as your first solution (I consider the second to be wrong), but with `\quad\rightarrow\quad`.

Comment: @alignmentnewbie if this answer has resolved the issue, you might consider 'accepting' it by clicking on the green check mark next to the answer :) Welcome!